# Adding textviews on button click android?

Tags: java, android

I've got a button that inserts user information into a database.
On top of this, I would like it to display the users entered details below in a list,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    insertuser();
    LinearLayout createworkout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.createworkout);
    TextView x = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    x.setText(editTextExercise.toString());
    createworkout.addView(x);
}
```

This is what I have so far. When clicking the button the information is inserted, but I can not see a visible Textview. No errors are thrown either, I don't know what I have done wrong here.

All help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: x.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); maybe will help.

Comment: two things may be there... first change the `getApplicationContext` to your `activity.this` .. and 2.  check your layout(`createworkout`) has not fixed height and width.. may be it is not showing ,, but added.

Comment: Layout is set to match parent

Answer (score 0):

Have your LinearLayout orientation property set?

try to add:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: It is set as vertical in the xml

Comment: So, maybe add LayoutParams to the TextView?

Comment: Added and still not visible

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it as...

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
insertuser();
 LinearLayout createworkout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.createworkout);
    TextView x = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
    x.setText(editTextExercise.toString());
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams ( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    createworkout.addView(x,lp);
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, does not work for me unfortunately. No errors are thrown but no textview is visible still

Comment: ok try to set it as ... `x.setText("This is text view");` 
i think you are not getting the text to set on textview..